# Growing XML with variation conditions and static data. Looking for alternative

Tags: java, xml

In our Java application, we have used XMLs to maintain static data and variation conditions. Now these XMLs are growing beyond control. What would be an alternative to maintain our static data and variation conditions which will benefit us in terms of performance cost and usability?

Comment: What exactly does "growing beyond control" mean? What problems are you having? What is the nature of your data?

Comment: Why not use database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you said you read the XML file in each request, if you use JAX-B or is getting in as object somehow, after load this files make a Singleton (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to hold this values in memory, this way you will validate the XML just once and will keep it in memory, increasing the performance.
But, if the XML is really huge and you can not maintain they in memory, I would suggest putting this information in a database. You could migrate all the data to the database or create a functionality to update the data on system startup according to the XML data. The best solution in this scenario with database would be migrate all data and not use XML anymore.
To measure the performance of each approach you would have to write something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date initialDate = new Date();
    getXmlValue();// or getDBValue();
    Date finalDate = new Date();
    System.out.println("Load XML took " + (initialDate.getTime()-finalDate.getTime()) + "ms");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can i evaluate the performance benefit which i am getting currently with XML with the performance benefit which i can get with DB approach. Basically how i can conclude i ave to move my xml(s) to DB?

Comment: Well you would have to do something like:
Date initialDate = new Date();
getXmlValue();
Date finalDate = new Date();
System.out.println("Load XML took " + initialDate.getTime()-finalDate.getTime());
I'll update the answer with this code.

Comment: Please @ams2705 upvote my answer if you liked it. This way I can contrinute better with comments. Thanks.